# A strange behavior when I append to a list in Python

Tags: python, list, append

I am looking for the [Josephus_problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josephus_problem) ,but the result is not my Expected. Why?

```
def J(n,x):
    li=range(1,n+1)
    k=0
    res=[]
    while len(li)>1:
        k= (x+k-1) % len(li)
        li.pop(k)
        res.append(li)
        #print li
    return res

print J(5,3)
```

Expected Output:

```
[1, 2, 4, 5]

[2, 4, 5]

[2, 4]

[4]
```

Actual Output:

```
[[4], [4], [4], [4]]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to append copy of list here:

```
res.append(li[:]) # <-- not res.append(li) !!!
```

The actual reason of what's going on it that `list` is mutable data structure in Python. Look at this snippet

```
>>> l = [1,2,3]
>>> p = [l,l,l]    
>>> p
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
>>> l.pop()
3
>>> p
[[1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 2]]
```